# Cassandra materialized view shows stale data

Tags: cassandra, cql

I was trying out the Cassandra 3.0 alpha to see how materialized views work and following the example shown [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views).

The example works when a whole partition is deleted from the base table, but when I delete an individual clustered row, it continues to appear in the materialized view.  Shouldn't a row deleted in the base table also disappear from the views?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE base (part int, clus int , val int, PRIMARY KEY (part, clus));
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view1 AS SELECT part FROM base WHERE part IS NOT NULL AND clus IS NOT NULL AND val IS NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (val, part, clus);
INSERT INTO base (part, clus, val) VALUES ( 1, 2, 200 );
INSERT INTO base (part, clus, val) VALUES ( 1, 3, 300 );

SELECT * FROM view1;

 val | part | clus
-----+------+------
 200 |    1 |    2
 300 |    1 |    3
```

Then I delete just one of the rows:

```
DELETE FROM base WHERE part=1 and clus=3;
```

Now I was expecting val=300 to disappear from the view, but it didn't:

```
SELECT * FROM view1;

 val | part | clus
-----+------+------
 200 |    1 |    2
 300 |    1 |    3
```

Next if I delete the whole partition, the clustering row I deleted earlier is left behind in the view:

```
DELETE FROM base WHERE part=1;

SELECT * from base;

 clus | part | val
------+------+-----

SELECT * FROM view1;

 val | part | clus
-----+------+------
 300 |    1 |    3
```

I'm guessing this is a bug in the alpha release, but wanted to make sure this isn't the expected behavior.  Should I be able to delete individual clustered rows and see that reflected in the materialized views?

I'm using this release:

```
nodetool version
ReleaseVersion: 3.0.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both deletes and updates should be propagated to the view according to "[Cassandra 3.0 materialised views in action](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com.es/2015/07/cassandra-30-materialised-views-in.html)".

Comment: I guess it's a bug then since I think I'm entering the correct commands.  Thanks for the link.  I've seen very few examples of materialized views so far.

Comment: This bug has been addressed in [CASSANDRA-10014](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10014), thanks for reporting!

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out when the next build comes out.  I'm looking forward to running some performance tests.

Comment: I am using cassandra 3.3 , is this issue still exist? because I encounter the same problem.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11198