# cassandra materialized view show stale data

Tags: database, cassandra

Sorry to ask same question again, but the question seems not solved yet. So I post it again. according to this question , 
[Cassandra materialized view shows stale data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810841/cassandra-materialized-view-shows-stale-data)

We encounter the same problem in cassandra 3.3 where one record in base table is deleted but is not reflected in MV.  Especially the one composite key of Materialized view from base table is null.

This is an issue posted in Feb 2016
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11198.

Any method to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some JIRA related to Materialized Views inconsistencies:

- **[CASSANDRA-11500](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11500)**
- **[CASSANDRA-11475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11475)**